# Always run on hardware

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I do my Android development exclusively on my actual phone, and I want to be able to run my program without having to go through the Android device chooser every time I launch, but even when I check the "Use same device for future launches" box, I still get prompted to choose a device. Do you know what I can do to always run on that device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go in to the menu `Run -> Run Configuration...` and in the configuration of your project, under the tab `Target`, check and make sure it's set to `automatic`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. But I use a workaround, selecting "Launch on all compatible devices/ADVs", and selecting "Active devices". That launch the thing on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested:

```
Run Configurations -> Target Tab
```

Then set `Deployment Target Selection Mode` to automatic instead of manual.